# Bootstrap 2 or Bootstrap 3 for IE 7 Performance Wise

Tags: performance, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7, twitter-bootstrap-3

While I know SO does not like A vs B topics hear me out.

Bootstrap 3 has just been released with countless improvements. The one potential deal breaker is it drops IE 7 compatibility. For site's that cater to corporate users this unfortunately isn't practical since that in one particular use case is roughly 10% market still.

So supporting IE7 is a must which one would think that simply means choosing to stick with Bootstrap 2. However, with this https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7 one can easily add IE7 support back while keeping all the benefits of Bootstrap 3.

The one issue their is you must use boxsizing.htc polyfill for IE 7 users (https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill)

So my question would it be better to stick with Bootstrap 2 or switch to Bootstrap 3.0 with boxsizing.htc? B3 with .htc will be slower for the 10% IE7 users than with B2, but if barely noticeable (especially if server is caching) it would be worth it for the benefits to the rest of the 90%.

If know one knows, the next thing I guess I could test is installing the default B2 and B3 with .htc demo sites and comparing the speeds in IE7.

PS If there is a better polyfill for adding boxsizing to IE7 than the one listed above performance wise let me know.

Comment: Take my advice; don't use Bootstrap(a mobile-first framework) when you're considering IE-7 users as first-class citizens.

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow. I don't consider IE7 users first class citizens but as mentioned if 10% of a particular site's userbase is IE7, that is simply too much to ignore when the users are business users looking to signup for a product. With the above example IE7 users won't be getting rounded corners, text shadows and other first class citizen features. However, without boxresizing in B3 the layout would break so that needs to be supported.

Comment: Do you want to migrate your website to TB3? See: http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/its-a-shame-the-newest-version-of-githubs-most-popular-projects-is-not-backward-compatible/

Comment: @Bass Nope, the post above is not about migrating from B2 to B3. This post is just about whether to choose Boostrap 2 or Bootstrap 3 with a BoxSizing.htc polyfill, in regards to the benefits weighed with the performance concerns listed above.

Comment: Any case read the blog :) It handles that question too. TB2 is stable and ready for production TB not (at the moment). Will mobile first be a benefit for your users? I think it depends on the product and target. Do you have a idea of the life time of your project? With a short expected life time i should try to not hurt your 10% IE7 users, with a long expected life time i should choose the newest  technology.

Comment: Sorry but I did read the blog and it does not answer my question. Also as noted yes B3 would be beneficial to the users for all expects except for not supporting IE7 natively. Also as noted ignoring 10% of the user base is not an option. I want to use B3 but would have to use boxsizing.htc which would hurt IE7 performance compared to BS2. A little performance hit is fine but this question is about how much that performance hit might be and thus if it's worth using BS2 or BS3.

Comment: I would suggest to stay with ver 2 whenever you have to support IE7... boxsizing polyfill is messing with bootsrap's js... I couldn't make collapsibles working on ie7 using boxsizing.htc :(

Comment: @DS_web_developer I think collapsibles should work with bootstrap-ie7 and boxsizing.htc but will have to double check. Though I'm not using that particular component on this site so still only concerned about performance implications.

Comment: @heavymark Since you posted the original question quite a few improvements have been made to https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7 which now only applies the boxsizing polyfill to the necessary elements so performance is a lot better. I personally recommend Bootstrap 3 and using that IE7 CSS conditional CSS for those folks with IE7. You may need to add additional CSS fixes/tweaks depending on your site layout.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar dilemma with Bootstrap 3/IE7, but landed on a different solution. Like Zout, I couldn't get the patch to work, so I wrote one that doesn't require a polyfill.

It works by falling back to a Bootstrap 2 type grid system of fluid columns with no padding and a left margin beginning with the second column. In IE7 with Bootstrap 3, my site looks perfect.

I've tested it (and it works) with most of the components of Bootstrap. It also includes fixes for IE layout bugs and other odd behaviors.

I just put it on Github yesterday. Hope it helps:

https://github.com/LPology/Bootstrap-IE7Fix

Comment: I tried both the boxsizing.htc method and your method. For me the boxsizing approach worked very well. Do make sure that the htc file is served with the right mime type, as mentioned onhttps://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill
Your method also showed an improved layout, but extra margins appeared between elements that broke the layout. Both approaches also improved the rendering on IE6 to an almost fixable state.

Comment: @konrad Which elements had extra margins that broke the layout? The columns do, but they're fluid and the width is adjusted to account for that. I actually took them directly from Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Comment: I have rows that contain a whole bunch of blocks, more than fit onto one row. I'm not sure this would work with Bootstrap 2, but it works beautifully with Bootstrap 3. I noticed that there was a difference between the first and other rows. There was also a gutter between blocks inside the row. The boxsizing.htc hack worked very well and kept all block right next to each other without a gutter. But even if your box model fix is not of any help to me, there are plenty of other fixes in your file that might prove useful!

Comment: @user1091949 just saw your repo and it would be great if you have a link to sample site using this fix for bootstrap 3.

Comment: @Yoda Done. Link added to README.md

Answer (score 1):

It is a complete nightmare to support IE 7 with Bootstrap 3. We tried it and needed to switch back to Bootstrap 2 for our new project.

We did try the patches you mentioned.

So bottom line: Do you really need to support IE 7, don't use Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Thanks, ultimately since supporting IE7 was a requirement due to the overwhelming high use in our analytics (contrary to what Microsoft and many survey's say) as you probably know. Since IE7 support will still be needed for the forseeable future I'm still interested in getting IE7 support in Bootstrap. While it may be a complete nightmare the first time around I'm fine with that if I have more time on my next project. Still hoping someone is able to answer the question based on a concreate Performance comparison. Eventually I'll try doing the comparisons myself and will post results.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 has dropped support for IE7 but there is an alternative github repo you can use that supports IE7, it can be found here: https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7